# ASP.NET MVC API Post Data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an API in MVC. It is configured as follows:

```
config.EnableCors();
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "API/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I am using Custom routing for my API to make restful services an Example is the following Controller

```
[RoutePrefix("datapi/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
    [Route("getuser/{userid}/")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public ObjUser GetUserObject(string userid)
    {
        ObjUser user = this.userdata.GetUser(userid);
        return user;
    }

    [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
    [Route("updatepassword")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ObjUser UpdateUserPassword(string userid, string password)
    {
        ObjUser user = this.userdata.GetUser(userid);
        user.Password = password;
        this.userdata.SaveUser(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

The 'getuser' method works fine. I get the Object in Json Format in my applicaiton

The trouble arises when I use HttpPost service (updatepassword). I trying to send data via HttpPost and it gives me a CORS error which says

> "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
>   reading the remote resource"

Is there something wrong with my config?

The following is the test I have done for both

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3351/datapi/user/updatepassword'
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    userid: 'joe.brandt@email.com',
    password: 'newpassword'
  },
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3351/datapi/user/getuser/joe.brandt@email.com'
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

***EDIT: MORE TEST RESULTS***

So I had a hunch and I tested the service as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3351/datapi/user/updatepassword/joe.brandt@email.com/somepassword'
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

This worked. But, if anyone of the inputs contains a colon ":" it gives a CORS error! The way forward is two paths, one restrict input of ":" and the second one is convert it into unicode. The API is restful but some other guy suggessted to give data in Ajax data as payload, will that work with restful api?

Comment: did you set `crossDomain` as `true` in the ajax request? try it

Comment: Do I need to? I am using EnableCors in MVC and the getuser works fine why is that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution that we have reached to is to make a complex structure with userid and password as it's properties and we have changed the method like this

```
public ObjUser UpdateUserPassword(ApiUserParam userParam)
{
    ObjUser user = this.userdata.GetUser(userParam.userid);
    user.Password = userParam.password;
    this.userdata.SaveUser(user);
    return user;
}
```

And now I have a working web service with Post and completely restful too.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line of code to `Register` method of WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "POST"));
```

Comment: I believe it's not a CORS issue anymore please check my edited post